# Javascript in Mobileweb in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

Is it possible to use javascript in Mobile .NET, if yes please let me know how we can do that. Please post Link to the helping article for javascript in Mobile .NET if you know some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a forum with nearly the identical question:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1184277.aspx

You may find the links he references to be able to answer your question.

The short answer is that you can, on some devices, as not all devices support javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This one is helpful:

It's possible but it works on devices that support Javascript. Check up links below for greater details:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/764b113c-2b3a-4b78-8a68-72d2c53b8470/make-your-aspnet-mobile.aspx